# Escaped asterisk (*) in list of characters outputs file in folder

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, asterisk

At the very beginning of my Bash script I'm passing a set of characters like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set0="0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
set1="° § + \" ç % & / ( ) = ? ' ^ ! £ $ - _ ; , : . *"
```

The script combines every single character with the others in order to get all possible combination with length of `n`.

As you can see in `set1` above I have to escape the quote `"` character for example. My problem now is, that I have to escape the asterisk `*` as well. But I couldn't figure out how.

This didn't work so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
set1="° § + \" ç % & / ( ) = ? ' ^ ! £ $ - _ ; , : . \*"
```

It echoes `\*`. If I don't escape the asterisk `*` with a backslash `\` the script echoes all the files in current directory all time.

Do you know how I can escape the asterisk `*` successfully?

---

This is the whole script:

```
  8 chars0="a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"
  9 chars1="A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"
 10 chars2="0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
 11 chars3="° § + \" ç % & / ( ) = ? ' ^ ! £ $ - _ ; , : . *"
 12 
 13 function increment {
 14         INPUT=$1
 15         [[ ${#INPUT} -ge $minlen ]]  && echo $1
 16         if [[ ${#INPUT} -lt $maxlen ]]; then
 17                 for c in $chars; do
 18                         increment $1$c
 19                 done
 20         fi
 21 }
 22 
 23 function showUsage {
 24         echo "$0 MAXLEN [MINLEN] [a [A [n [p]]]]"
 25         echo
 26         echo "  MAXLEN  integer Maximum lenght, or specific lengt if MINLEN is omitted"
 27         echo "  MINLEN  integer Minimum lenght, equals MAXLEN if omitted"
 28         echo ""
 29         echo "  characters:"
 30         echo "  a       lower case      a-z"
 31         echo "  A       Uppercase       A-Z"
 32         echo "  n       numeric         0-9"
 33         echo "  p       punctuation     . ?" 
 34 }
 35 
 36 
 37 
 38 
 39 ## argument handler
 40 [[ "$1" = "" ]] && showUsage && exit
 41 maxlen=$1
 42 [[ $2 -eq 0 ]] && minlen=$maxlen || minlen=$2
 43 
 44 
 45 for arg in "$@"; do
 46         case $arg in
 47                 a) chars="$chars $chars0" ;;
 48                 A) chars="$chars $chars1" ;;
 49                 n) chars="$chars $chars2" ;;
 50                 p) chars="$chars $chars3" ;;
 51         esac;
 52 done
 53 
 54 #fallback
 55 [[ "$chars" = "" ]] && chars="$chars0"
 56 
 57 
 58 
 59 ## kickof
 60 
 61 for i in $chars; do
 62         increment $i
 63 done
```

Comment: That's not where the problem is.

Comment: You don't have to escape the wildcard. ***You have to use more quotes.*** Show the remaining part of the code and we'll show you where you missed mandatory quotes.

Comment: I just added the whole script.

Comment: A quick fix: use `set -f` at the beginning of the script. But your design is very bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your suggestions. The one that helped me fixing this was

```
set -f
```

It's a quick fix of course. But it works well for me.

Comment: Works well, but your design is not good. What if, one day, you want to also have a space in your character pool?

Comment: **Good question.** I guess I've to re-think the design once again.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is maybe to use:

```
set -o noglob
set="* + ?"
for i in $set; do echo $i; done
*
+
?
```

The problem when you use the variable. `noglob` will prevent all of the file glob characters from expanding.

Comment: Nope, the error is only in the `for i in $set`, not in the variable assignment. Well, there's also potential globbing in the `echo $i` statement too.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf my mistake, I'll update, but I still think the safest way is with `noglob`.

Comment: The design is broken anyway. OP will never be able to have spaces in character pool. Good design uses arrays. Or another possibility is to loop on the characters of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't safely loop on a list of words in a string like this, without having nasty globbing effects. In your case, it boils down to this:

```
a=*
for i in $a; do
    echo "$a"
done
```

You'll see that the files in your current directory are printed, because the (unquoted! horror!) `$a` in the `for` statement expands to `*` which will glob to the list of files in current dir.

You must fix this by using another design. You're lucky, Bash supports arrays very well, so redesign your code to use arrays. For example:

```
chars=( ° § + \" ç % \& / '(' ')' = \? \' ^ ! £ $ - _ \; , : . \* )
```

(this defines the *array* `chars`) and to loop through that:

```
for i in "${chars[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

(observe the quotes).

---

Below is a rewriting of your code to show you how to use arrays (and I've fixed/improved some other minor stuff too):

```
#!/bin/bash

chars_alpha=( {a..z} )
chars_ALPHA=( {A..Z} )
chars_digit=( {0..9} )
chars_punct=( '°' '§' '+' '"' 'ç' '%' '&' '/' '(' ')' '=' '?' "'" '^' '!' '£' '$' '-' '_' ';' ',' ':' '.' '*' )

increment() {
   local input=$1
   (( ${#input} >= minlen )) && printf '%s\n' "$input"
   if (( ${#input} < maxlen )); then
      for c in "${chars[@]}"; do
         increment "$input$c"
      done
   fi
}

showUsage() {
   cat <<EOF
$0 MAXLEN [MINLEN] [a] [A] [n] [p]

  MAXLEN  integer Maximum lenght, or specific lengt if MINLEN is omitted
  MINLEN  integer Minimum lenght, equals MAXLEN if omitted

  characters:
  a       lower case      a-z
  A       Uppercase       A-Z
  n       numeric         0-9
  p       punctuation     . ? etc.
EOF
}

## argument handler
(($#)) || { showUsage; exit 1; }

[[ $1 = +([[:digit:]]) ]] || { showUsage; exit 1; }
((maxlen=10#$1))
shift

# Check that maxlen is >0 or exit gracefully
((maxlen>0)) || exit 0

if [[ $1 = +([[:digit:]]) ]]; then
   ((minlen=10#$1))
   shift
else
   ((minlen=maxlen))
fi

# Check that minlen<=maxlen otherwise swap them
if ((minlen>maxlen)); then
   ((temp=minlen,minlen=maxlen,maxlen=temp))
fi

chars=()

while (($#)); do
    case $1 in
    (a) chars+=( "${chars_alpha[@]}" ); chars_alpha=() ;;
    (A) chars+=( "${chars_ALPHA[@]}" ); chars_ALPHA=() ;;
    (n) chars+=( "${chars_digit[@]}" ); chars_digit=() ;;
    (p) chars+=( "${chars_punct[@]}" ); chars_punct=() ;;
    (*) printf >&2 'Ignored arguments %s\n' "$1" ;;
    esac
    shift
done

#fallback
(( ${#chars[@]} )) || chars=( "${chars_alpha[@]}" )

#kick off!
increment
```

One of the fixes includes using `printf` instead of `echo`. With `echo`, your code is broken, since the strings:

```
-e
-n
-E
```

would never be printed! see `help echo` to understand why. Try it yourself too:

```
echo -e
echo -n
echo -E
```

don't output anything!

Answer (score -1):

Use single quotes to wrap your string instead of double quotes. You won't have to have to escape any characters beside the single quote.